# PPV vs Sensitivity, they look the same!

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, f1

I am looking at the equation PPV and Sensitivity

and I got this

```
PPV = TP / (TF+FN)
```

and

```
Sensitivity = TP / (TF+FN)
```

Which means both are the same !!

So do we have them in 2 names?

and how come F1 Score is

```
F1 Score = 2*PPV*S / (PPV+S)
```

Can we rewrite F1 Score to be

```
F1 Score = 2*PPV*PPV / (PPV+PPV) = 2*PPV*PPV / (2*PPV) = PPV !!
```

They all the same?

It seems there is some condition or something I am missing here!

can someone please explain to me what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some typos. Formulas sholud be:

`PPV = TP / (TP+FP)`

and

`Sensitivity = TP / (TP+FN)`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity

Comment: I was looking at this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08705 and it says PPV = TP / (TF+FN) in page 7

Comment: First, you keep using "TF". What's TF? Second, arxiv paper has a typo too.